# launch CSS animation when appending and removing elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'd like to run a CSS animation when I .append and .remove.

Some example code:

```
$(".search-form").submit(function() {
    $("#box").remove();
    event.preventDefault();
    var searchText = $('#input-1').val();
    $('#input-1').val("");
    var searchURL = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&generator=search&gsrsearch=" + searchText + "&gsrlimit=15&prop=extracts&exsentences=3&exintro=&explaintext&exlimit=max&callback=JSON_CALLBACK";
    console.log(searchURL);
    var wikiResponse = wikiAjax(searchURL);
    wikiResponse.done(function(data) {
          console.log(data);
        $.each(data.query.pages, function(index, value) {
          var wikiResultHTML = '<div class="linkable-div"><a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/?curid=' + value.pageid + '"<div class="container"><article class="search-result row well"><div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-7 excerpet"><h3>' + value.title + '</h3><p>' + value.extract + '</p></div><span class="clearfix borda"></span></article></div></a></div>';
          $(".search-results").append(wikiResultHTML);
        });
        $('.linkable-div').click(function() {
           event.preventDefault();
           var wikiLink = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
           $('.linkable-div').remove();
           showBox();
           $("#iframe").attr('src', wikiLink);
        });

    }).fail(function(err) {
        alert("The call has been rejected");
    });
});
```

Can you help me please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: just put your code for animation after `.append` or `.remove` code, what's the problem?

Comment: and provide more of your code here. what are you appending/removing?

Comment: @Tinmar how? I've added some code. Thank you.

Comment: what kind of animation you want? fade in/out? or?

Comment: I don't know, i mean there are plenty of animation possibilities, if I am right. I need just a general rule to do so, if you want to show it with fade, it's ok for me. thanks.

Comment: I answered, hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume this `.linkable-div` is the one which should be animated. First of all - add `display:none;` property to it. So it won't show in usual way.

After that, add animation code, like this:

```
$(".linkable-div").fadeIn();
```

And instead of `.remove()` set `.fadeOut()`